# NotSerializableException at simple class implementing Serializable

Tags: java, exception, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a simple class `Sertest`. It has one member `Decision` which itself has only a `boolean` and an `int` member, both classes implement `Serializable`.
However I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException: Decision`.

`Decision.java`:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Decision implements Serializable {
    public final int chosenValue;
    public final boolean continuePlaying;

    public Decision(int chosenValue, boolean continuePlaying){
        this.chosenValue = chosenValue;
        this.continuePlaying = continuePlaying;
    }
}
```

`Sertest.java`:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Sertest implements Serializable {

    private Decision test;

    public Sertest(){
        this.test = new Decision(1, true);
    }

    public Decision getTest(){
        return test;
    }

}
```

And finally, my `Main.java` code:

```java
Sertest s = null;
        File f = new File("sertest.asdf");
        if(f.exists()){
            ObjectInputStream ois = null;
            try {
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
                s = (Sertest) ois.readObject();
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(ois != null) {
                    try {
                        ois.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            s = new Sertest();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
            try{
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
                oos.writeObject(s);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(oos != null) {
                    try {
                        oos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (s != null)
            System.out.println(s.getTest().chosenValue);
```

I searched and searched StackOverflow and Duckduckgo, but just can't find the reason for this. I tried:

- Refactoring the `Decision` class to have private members with getter methods
- Adding a noarg-constructor to `Decision`
- Debugging by setting a breakpoint in `ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2355)` (However this didn't work)

Comment: You aren't running the code you think you're running. Clean, build, deploy, re-test. Or else the file was created from an older version. Delete, re-test.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Code runs fine. Make sure your classes are recompiled and delete the `sertest.asdf` file, since it might have corrupt content.

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned, recompiled and deleted `sertest.asdf` and it worked fine!